# Open PDF file from file system with JSF and Viewer.js

Tags: javascript, jsf, tomcat, pdf, primefaces

I am working with JSF 2.0, Tomcat 7.0, 5.0 and primefaces Viewer.js on a project indexing pdf files do searches, show results and view documents. 
The problem is that I need to open PDF documents from the file system of the PC, I'm using Viewer.js considers that the best option for this project but still can not get get open Any idea how to do it? I only managed to get open inside the folder of my project.

The way as I try to open the documents is as follows:

```
<h:form id="form">
            <p:dataList id="bus" value="#{beanBusqueda.bus}" var="busqueda" type="unordered" itemType="none" paginator="true" rows="20" emptyMessage="Sin resultados por el momento" paginatorAlwaysVisible="true">
                <a href="http://localhost:8080/i-Bi/Viewer.js/#../file:///C:/directoriov1/#{busqueda.ruta}">Ver</a>
                <h:outputText value="#{busqueda.resultados}" id="info"/>
                <f:facet name="footer"><h:outputText value="#{beanBusqueda.buscar.info}" style="font-weight:normal"/></f:facet>
            </p:dataList>
        </h:form>
```

And I got my ManagedBean follows:

```
public void buscar() throws IOException{
    setBus(new ArrayList<csBuscar>());
    String resul="";
    try {

            directorio= FSDirectory.getDirectory(direct, false);
            searcher= new IndexSearcher(directorio);
            parser= new QueryParser("content", new StandardAnalyzer());
            long start= new Date().getTime();
            Query consulta= parser.parse(buscar.getBusqueda());
            Hits hits = searcher.search(consulta);
            long end= new Date().getTime();
            Document doc=null;

            if(hits.length()==0){
                buscar.setResultados("No se encontraron resultados para "+buscar.getBusqueda());
            }else{
                for(int i=0;i<hits.length();i++){
                    doc=hits.doc(i);
                    //resul+=doc.get("nombre").substring(0,doc.get("nombre").length()-4)+"\n";
                    bus.add(new csBuscar(doc.get("nombre").substring(0,doc.get("nombre").length()-4)+"\n", doc.get("nombre")));
                    System.out.println(doc.get("absolute"));
                }buscar.setResultados(resul);
                buscar.setInfo("Se muestran "+hits.length()+" resultados para "+buscar.getBusqueda()+" en "+(end-start)+" milisegundos.");
                System.out.println(buscar.getResultados());
            }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        searcher.close();
    }
}
```

I was also trying the following routes:

```
Viewer.js / # .. / C :/ directoriov1 / # {busqueda.ruta} 
http://localhost:8080/i-Bi/Viewer.js/ # .. / C :/ directoriov1 / # {busqueda.ruta}
```

But I can not get it open. 
Would I have to modify the code to get Viewer.js? 
Hope suggestions thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider use to this the document viewer of google?
This will be open in an iframe and you must only change the url of pdf.

https://docs.google.com/viewer

Example of Iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fs3.documentcloud.org%2Fdocuments%2F509922%2Ffernandez-cristina-elisabet-anual-2011.pdf&embedded=true" width="600" height="780" style="border: none;"></iframe>
```

Preview:
https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fs3.documentcloud.org%2Fdocuments%2F509922%2Ffernandez-cristina-elisabet-anual-2011.pdf

Saludos!

Comment: Try google docs think the problem is that you have to sign in to google drive for viewing, another problem is that you need to have stayed like Viewer.js document on the web server and it did not seem feasible for what I need. Anyway thanks for the suggestion.